# Excel Formula =PRODUCT(1+A1:A21)-1

Tags: excel, vba, product

I am trying to understand the formula `{PRODUCT(1+A1:A21)-1}` because for some reason, when executed thru VBA its returning value, but not when I type in the actual formula in a cell. Excelhelp has examples for `PRODUCT(A1:A21)`. I am trying to understand the significance of 1+ and -1 at the end.

Data from A1:A21 -

```
 0.00%
 0.28%
 0.19%
-0.02%
 0.03%
 0.15%
-0.24%
 0.17%
 0.59%
-0.16%
-0.28%
 0.58%
 0.31%
 0.10%
-0.11%
 0.40%
 0.04%
-0.48%
-0.23%
 0.17%
 0.04%
```

the output for the formula is 3.81% when executed thru VBA, but when I type the formula in a cell getting a `#value`!

Comment: You need to enter the formula (in Excel), as an *Array Formula*, by pressing <Ctrl> + <Shift> + <Enter>, rather than just <Enter>

Comment: and the adding and subtracting of 1 would seem to be related to the interest-rate nature of the data, and/or to offset the negative values for some of the values. Hard to say precisely without more detail of the nature of the data.

Comment: ah. so that's the trick. I also found the reason for adding 1+ from another example. It means adding a constant before doing a PRODUCT function and then subtract -1. Interesting. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

Because the PRODUCT function multiplies values together the result of any data set with an entry such as the first above will always be a not very useful `0`. The `+1` offsets all values to guarantee the result will never be `0` (before deduction of `1`).

The `-1` then removes the offset and for the data above the result is `0.0153` (or `1.53%`).

You should check your VBA if that is returning `3.81%`.

Answer (score 0):

> 1+A1:A21 means: (1+A1) * (1+A2) * ...(1+A21)
>
> 1+ ist there to compute 0 numbers too...
>
> -1 must by for cleaning